# Multiple joins between tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, join

I have following tables have multiple records each (~50k) and the tables are growing.

```
Table1
BatchID ID Record1

Table 2 
BatchID ID Record2

Table 3
BatchID ID Record3

Table 4 
BatchID ID Record4
```

The following query takes forever to run (as the join is the cartisian product of the four tables).

```
Select table1.batchid,
table1.ID,
table1.Record1, 
table2.Record2,
Table3.Record3, 
Table4.Record4 
from Table1 JOIN Table 2
on table1.batchID = table2.batchID and table1.ID = table2.ID
JOIN table3 
on table1.BatchID=table3.batchID and table1.ID = table3.ID 
JOIN table4 
on table1.ID = table4.ID and table1.batchID = table4.batchID
```

What should be the best way to do this.

Comment: both batchid and id are indexed..

Comment: I assume those WHEREs are actually ONs; if not they should be, although actually you could make this a lot tidier by joining each table with USING(id,batchid) instead. Other than that, all your tables should have indexes on (id,batchid) and that's about it - I wouldn't expect this query to take more than a fraction of a second really.

Comment: Need 1) structure/indices 2) query plan

Comment: That was a typo.. I have corrected it.. its on..

Comment: Oh, and if (batchid,id) is a unique combination then it should be a unique key rather than an index, but I can't tell if that's the case from the information here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you actually *need* all these JOINs? Can't you just merge these four tables together?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE MergedTable (
    BatchID INT,
    ID INT,
    Record1 ... ,
    Record2 ... ,
    Record3 ... ,
    Record4 ... ,
    PRIMARY KEY (BatchID, ID)
)
```

And then:

```
INSERT INTO MergedTable <your query>
```

You can now SELECT directly from MergedTable, without need for any JOINs.

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing finally... :)

Answer (score 3):

You should add indexes with both columns you are using in the `ON` clauses.  For example:

```
ALTER TABLE `table2` ADD INDEX `IDX_batchid-ID` (`batchid`, `ID`);
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thought is that you want a composite index on (batchid, id) on all four tables.  This will best match the join condition in the query.

How many records in the tables match each other with the same batchid and id?  There may be other ways to phrase the query.

Comment: I have indexes in all my tables including this.. All 50k records will match each other with same batchid and ID. BatchID and ID are composite keys in all tables..

Comment: Silly question.. but after I've created an index, do I join on the indexes or the actual table?

Comment: The SQL engine uses the indexes automatically.

Comment: You cant join on indexes only columns. Try using [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html) to check which indexes are used for each JOIN

Comment: I added batchID and ID as indexes to each of them as a combination and it still takes a lot of time..

Comment: Ouch . . . how many matches are there in the joins?  Are you getting one row from each table?

Comment: each table has around 50k results and are growing. All of them will match.. So 50K ^ 4 total combinations.. A big number..

Comment: So the batchid and id have the same value in all the records and all the tables?  If so, it will take a long time for the query to finish.  You might get the first rows sooner using a cross join.

Answer (score 1):

Your join looks fine.  Try creating an index on the combination of BatchID and ID.

[dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Comment: Silly question.. but after I've created an index, do I join on the indexes or the actual table? –

Comment: The join would be on the actual tables using the indexed columns.

Comment: I added batchID and ID as indexes to each of them as a combination and it still takes a lot of time..